# Is there anyway to permanently fix the Red Ring of Death?

Tags: xbox-360

I was thinking about buying some RROD Xbox 360s and JTag them and making a bit of cash. All the fixes i have found are only temporary.

Comment: First: this is more of a hardware question, Second: Its illegal

Comment: Ok let's say im not JTagging them. Is there a permanent fix?